# File.deleteRecursively() - how to delete the folder's content and not the folder itself

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a folder that contains picture files.
I use `File.deleteRecursively()` to delete the files, and it works perfectly,
but I must delete the content, not the 'Pictures' folder itself. How can that be done?

Comment: `File.deleteRecursively` is very poor at telling you when it fails to delete. Use [Path.deleteRecursively](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io.path/java.nio.file.-path/delete-recursively.html) instead, if you can.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
private static void deleteDirContent(String path){
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] allFiles = f.listFiles();
    if(allFiles == null)
        return;
    for (File f2 :
            allFiles) {
        if(f2.isFile()) {
            if (f2.delete()) {
                // this means file is deleted, everything is good
            } else {
                // was unable to delete the file, handle accordingly.
            }
        }
        else{
            f2.deleteRecursively();
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you have the right permissions of course.
For some reason I don't have deleteRecursively function, if it's Kotlin implementation then for Java you can add this function:

```
private static void deleteDirContentWithDir(String path){
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] allFiles = f.listFiles();
    if(allFiles == null)
        return;
    for (File f2 :
            allFiles) {
        if(f2.isFile()) {
            if (f2.delete()) {
                // this means file is deleted, everything is good
            } else {
                // was unable to delete the file, handle accordingly.
            }
        }
        else{
            deleteDirContentWithDir(f2.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    f.delete();
}
```

This will delete the dir content. In general, you can combine them to a single function:

```
private static void deleteDirContent(String path, boolean delWithDir){
    File f = new File(path);
    File[] allFiles = f.listFiles();
    if(allFiles == null)
        return;
    for (File f2 :
            allFiles) {
        if(f2.isFile()) {
            if (f2.delete()) {
                // this means file is deleted, everything is good
            } else {
                // was unable to delete the file, handle accordingly.
            }
        }
        else{
            deleteDirContent(f2.getAbsolutePath(), true);
        }
    }
    if(delWithDir)
        f.delete();
}
```

This basically says, delete a directory content, including directories that might have content and lets you decide if you want to delete the directory it self using the boolean parameter

Comment: This won't delete non-empty directories. You need deleteRecursively for that.

Comment: Well Dan twist your code a little to delete first all files and then recursively the directories. We are waiting..

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Kotlin version 1.8 or later, there is a new extension function on `java.nio.files.Path` which is preferable to `File.deleteRecursively` because it gives you more information (through exceptions) when a file cannot be deleted. It is currently "experimental":

```
import kotlin.io.path.*

@OptIn(ExperimentalPathApi::class)
fun deleteDirectoryContents(dir: String) {
    Path(dir).forEachDirectoryEntry { it.deleteRecursively() }
}
```